# How to get real-time download statistics when using wget

Tags: linux, centos, wget

I'm using `wget` on a centos machine to download certain websites, and I'm trying to download all the pages on the site (with recursive depth of 5):

`sudo wget --no-clobber --convert-links --random-wait -r -p --level 5 -E -e robots=off -U mozilla <somewebsite>`

All seems to function well but I want real-time information, i.e. how many pages `wget` has downloaded.

Thanks in advance.